# Driving from Seattle to Campbell River, BC

Tags: transportation, ferries, vancouver, seattle, vancouver-island

I want to drive from Seattle, WA to Campbell River, BC but I'm not sure what to do.
Does anyone know if there's a direct drive from Seattle to BC (Vancouver area)?

Can I do a straight drive or would I need to go through a ferry crossing?  If so, what is ferry cost for my car at the ferry crossing?

Comment: Campbell River is on an Island.  Does your car float?

Comment: I didn't need a ferry to go to Key West, FL.  It's an island.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to take a ferry to Vancouver Island. According to Google Maps the Tsawwassen-Duke Point (Nanaimo) ferry is most efficient - just put "Seattle, WA to Campbell River, BC" into Google Maps. You could also take the Tsawwassen - Swartz Bay ferry, or even the Anacortes - Sidney, BC ferry, there are probably other routes as well. BC ferry fares are listed at http://www.bcferries.com/files/fares/pdf_format/BCF_Fares.pdf , more info at http://www.bcferries.com/schedules/mainland/tsdp-current.php , and the Anacortes ferry is at http://www.wsdot.wa.gov/ferries/fares/FaresDetail.aspx?tripdate=&departingterm=1&arrivingterm=19